# What is the pronunciation and IPA symbol for the final 'r' sound?

Tags: pronunciación, consonantes

There is a recording here of a good example word, "robar":

http://www.spanishdict.com/translate/robar

I think I understand the rolling or trilling of the initial "r" sound. I'm wondering about the final sound. Is it the same tongue position as the initial, but with a single "hit" (no rolling), or do I hear a rolling that is a little softer or more subtle, or something else entirely? Maybe it varies by region and accent.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> In *word*-final position the rhotic is usually:
>
> - either a tap or a trill when followed by a consonant or a pause, as in *amo[r ~ ɾ] paterno* ('paternal love'), the former being more common;<sup>[43]</sup>
> - a tap when followed by a vowel-initial word, as in *amo[ɾ] eterno* ('eternal love').
>
> When two rhotics occur consecutively across a word or prefix boundary, they result in one trill, so that *da rocas* ('s/he gives rocks') and *dar rocas* ('to give rocks') are either neutralized, or distinguished by a longer trill in the latter phrase.<sup>[44]</sup>
>
> ...
>
> <sup>43, 44: Hualde, José Ignacio (2005), *The Sounds of Spanish* (p.182-183; p.184)</sup>

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spanish_phonology#Rhotics

Answer (score 3):

The phoneme for a word-final *r* is /r/, which is generally trilled, that is [r], in most dialects, although it's also possible for an untrilled sound based on emphasis and other contextual factors.

Other variations by dialect may include phones such as [ʐ], [ɻ], [ʁ], [x] or [χ].  In others, it may be silent, or function as a consonant-lengthener, lengthening the *following* consonant (such that *carne* is [kan:e]).  In still others, it may merge with the /l/ phoneme.